# SQL Server : concatenating values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following SQL Server query need help

```
select 
    JI.id, RBIEnvironment
from
   (select 
       issue,
       case when cfname='RBI-Environment' 
              then customvalue 
             else null 
       end as 'RBIEnvironment' 
    from X) as CT
where 
    CT.issue = JI.id
group by 
    JI.id, RBIEnvironment
```

The issue is the `CT` table returns the data in following format

```
1   NULL
1   STG
1   PROD
2   SIT
2   DIT
3   SIT
```

Hence the outer query returns

```
1   NULL
1   STG
1   PROD
2   SIT
2   DIT
3   SIT
```

I need in following format

```
1   STG,PROD
2   SIT,DIT
3   SIT
```

Please use the same inner dynamic table as such as it contains some more columns which needs to be displaye din the resultselt .This inner table is linked with the outer table using the issue field and ID field respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`STUFF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function for that:

```
SELECT distinct ID, RBIEnvironment = 
    STUFF((SELECT ' , ' + RBIEnvironment
           FROM MyTable b 
           WHERE b.ID = a.ID
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM MyTable a
GROUP BY ID;
```

Output:

```
| ID | RBIENVIRONMENT |
-----------------------
|  1 |     STG , PROD |
|  2 |      SIT , DIT |
|  3 |            SIT |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7172c/2)

Comment: @hims056,
I have modified your fiddle , as my slect table is a dynamic one and thus it fails.

Comment: @Alfaromeo - Can you show what you want exactly?

Comment: Thanks,but my requirement is that the inner  dynamic table is required whereas here it is already created.If I use the  alias ,invalid object error occurs.

Comment: @Alfaromeo - Can you show your code in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7172c/2)

Comment: Any luck withe the code

Comment: @Alfaromeo - I can't understand what exactly you want to do :( Can you explain with some expected result?

Comment: Your code is good ,the only issue is that the inner table already exist.For me the table is an alias of the select query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`STUFF..FOR XML`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/05/sql-server-group-by-rows-and-columns-using-xml-path-efficient-concating-trick/) construct for concatenating column values.

```
WITH CT AS 
(
    select issue,
        case when cfname='RBI-Environment' 
                then customvalue 
             else null 
             end as 'RBIEnvironment' 
    from X
)
SELECT issue, 
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + b.RBIEnvironment 
       FROM CT b 
        WHERE a.issue = b.issue 
         FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM CT a
GROUP BY a.issue
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0eb88/1)** - simplified for `CT` CTE